# App working fine on emulator but crashes after downloading from store

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've developed an Windows Phone 8 app which is under beta testing and it is working fine on emulator without fail or crash. but after submitting the app on store as beta version and then download the app on device it load the home page and on navigating through home page it crashing. Actually I dont have the device to test, the error is reported by the beta users. I'm not getting that why my app is facing this error if it is working fine on emulator.
Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: 9 times out of 10, it's a localization issue. Do you use `double.Parse` or `DateTime.Parse` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, i'm using DateTime.Parse, so how to get rid of this?

Comment: Its very difficult to answer such question. as any configuration change in your system will not be known on our side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an application that is going to be used worldwide, you must keep in mind that different countries use different ways of formatting dates or formatting number. When you use a parse method (double.Parse, DateTime.Parse, ...) without specifying a culture, the user's culture will be used, which often leads to crashes.

The workaround is simply to specify the culture you want to use. In the case of a date, you can event specify the precise date format you want to use.

```
// Parse a number by forcing the culture to en-US
double.Parse("13.25", CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US")); 

// Parse a date by forcing the culture to en-US
DateTime.Parse("12/31/2011", CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US"));

// Parse a date by specifying the format
DateTime.ParseExact("12/31/2011", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US"));
```

Comment: What if I'm using like this `new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat`? in the `DateTime.ParseExact` Method

Comment: @AmitKumar Is that what you're already doing in the crashing version, or what you intend to do?

Comment: @AmitKumar Then it probably means that the problem is the other way around: the date you're parsing is formatted differently depending on the culture, and you're always expecting the same format. Where do you get that date from?

Comment: I'm getting the date from my app cloud which is in the MM/dd/yyyy format always.

Comment: May be the problem can exist somewhere else. its hard to guess like this without device testing :)

Comment: @AmitKumar You can start by going in the preferences in the emulator and changing the language/format settings. Also, add some crash reporting feature in your app by using the Application.UnhandledException event. This way, users will be able to send you the full stacktrace, and you'll pinpoint easily the cause of the crash

Comment: I think the problem is there only. I changed the country and the crash on emulator. will check the problem later now. thanks for the help.